# How to perform multiple operations for each column in matrix in R without using FOR loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

suppose I have data frame as follows in R workspace

```
   a b c d
s  1 2 3 4
t  2 4 5 6
u  1 9 7 6
v  9 2 3 4
w  3 2 0 2
x  3 2 0 9
y  9 2 4 3
z  8 3 4 5
```

How do I automate to extract range, mean, standard deviation, median, maximum and minimum for each column of matrix without using FOR LOOPS in R? Is it possible to employ apply/sapply/lapply??

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different options for this case.  Others have mentioned the `apply` function, but `apply` works on a matrix and if given a data frame it will first convert it to a matrix before applying the function.  For the sample data frame this will not be a problem (but it will be inefficient to convert first), but it could cause problems if used with a data frame that contains non-numeric columns.

Better is to use `sapply` which works directly on lists (and a data frame is a form of a list):

```
> sapply(mtcars, function(x) c(mean(x), median(x), sd(x)))
           mpg      cyl     disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec
[1,] 20.090625 6.187500 230.7219 146.68750 3.5965625 3.2172500 17.848750
[2,] 19.200000 6.000000 196.3000 123.00000 3.6950000 3.3250000 17.710000
[3,]  6.026948 1.785922 123.9387  68.56287 0.5346787 0.9784574  1.786943
            vs        am      gear   carb
[1,] 0.4375000 0.4062500 3.6875000 2.8125
[2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 4.0000000 2.0000
[3,] 0.5040161 0.4989909 0.7378041 1.6152
```

You can compute whichever functions you want on each column by changing the function above.

You may also want to consider the dplyr package which has functions to do things like this in a form that may be a little more readable and will adapt to more complicated cases in a simpler ways.

```
> library(dplyr)
> mtcars %>% summarise_each(funs(mean,median,sd))
  mpg_mean cyl_mean disp_mean  hp_mean drat_mean wt_mean qsec_mean vs_mean
1 20.09062   6.1875  230.7219 146.6875  3.596563 3.21725  17.84875  0.4375
  am_mean gear_mean carb_mean mpg_median cyl_median disp_median hp_median
1 0.40625    3.6875    2.8125       19.2          6       196.3       123
  drat_median wt_median qsec_median vs_median am_median gear_median
1       3.695     3.325       17.71         0         0           4
  carb_median   mpg_sd   cyl_sd  disp_sd    hp_sd   drat_sd     wt_sd
1           2 6.026948 1.785922 123.9387 68.56287 0.5346787 0.9784574
   qsec_sd     vs_sd     am_sd   gear_sd carb_sd
1 1.786943 0.5040161 0.4989909 0.7378041  1.6152

> mtcars %>% summarise_each(funs(mean,median,sd)) %>% 
  matrix(nrow=ncol(mtcars), dimnames=list(names(mtcars), c('Mean','Median','SD')))
     Mean     Median SD       
mpg  20.09062 19.2   6.026948 
cyl  6.1875   6      1.785922 
disp 230.7219 196.3  123.9387 
hp   146.6875 123    68.56287 
drat 3.596563 3.695  0.5346787
wt   3.21725  3.325  0.9784574
qsec 17.84875 17.71  1.786943 
vs   0.4375   0      0.5040161
am   0.40625  0      0.4989909
gear 3.6875   4      0.7378041
carb 2.8125   2      1.6152
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(df, 2, summary)
           a    b    c     d
#Min.    1.00 2.00 0.00 2.000
#1st Qu. 1.75 2.00 2.25 3.750
#Median  3.00 2.00 3.50 4.500
#Mean    4.50 3.25 3.25 4.875
#3rd Qu. 8.25 3.25 4.25 6.000
#Max.    9.00 9.00 7.00 9.000
```

Comment: Or `sapply(df, summary)`. To get range, use `sapply(df, range)`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that `sapply` did that :)

Comment: Or just summary(df).  Summary will apply itself to all columns.

Comment: `summary` function was merely an example so as to show the OP how to iterate over columns

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <- c('mean', 'sd', 'median', 'min', 'max')
sapply(fun, function(x) apply(dff, 2, match.fun(x)))
```

You will get Output like this,

```
   mean       sd median min max
a 4.500 3.545621    3.0   1   9
b 3.250 2.434866    2.0   2   9
c 3.250 2.375470    3.5   0   7
d 4.875 2.167124    4.5   2   9
```